# Specify connection timeout in java.nio

Tags: java, timeout, connection, nio

Using non-blocking I/O, the code for connecting to a remote address looks something like:

```
SocketChannel channel = SelectorProvider.provider().openSocketChannel();
channel.configureBlocking(false);
channel.connect(address);
```

The connection process will then have to be finished by invoking `finishConnect()` on the channel when some selector says the corresponding key `isConnectable()`.

Is there a way to specify the connection timeout when using this idiom?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I'm not sure that nio itself provides a solution.

In my experience, I've run a Callable to attempt the connection, and then used the Future to poll for a response, using 'interval' and 'timeout' variables to loop and Thread.sleep() for a response.

Hopefully that points you in a useful direction ...

Also, I suggest you take a look at Apache Mina (you could describe Mina as an nio framework). It handles a lot of this kind of stuff for you, for example in the StreamIoHandler http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/handler/stream/StreamIoHandler.html

Answer (score -2):

The question doesn't really make sense. Timeouts are for blocking mode. If you want that, leave the channel in blocking mode and call `channel.socket().connect(address, timeout);`. If you want non-blocking mode, use your current code; then create a Selector; register the channel for `OP_CONNECT`; when you get it call `finishConnect(),` and if that returns true deregister `OP_CONNECT` and continue with the rest of your code.

Comment: The question does make sense. It's perfectly fine to start an asynchronous socket connection and want it to either connect in a certain amount of time or give up and tell you (via OP_CONNECT) that it timed out. It's just that nio doesn't expose that second `Socket.connect()` parameter, so I think this is not feasible via nio.

Comment: @LucioPaiva You are conflating asynchronous and non-blocking mode. They are different things.