# How does one implement a timeout in blocking mode NIO?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, io, nio

I'm not using any selectors or anything like that. I just have a simple `ServerSocketChannel` listening and a `SocketChannel` connecting to it in blocking mode. I want to impose a timeout on the connection, but `SocketChannel.socket().setSoTimeout()` does not work.

I tried making a background thread sleep for 30 seconds and checking if a variable is still `null` (since it will block waiting to read into that variable) but I couldn't synchronize the variable properly in that I could not access the local variable in my anonymous class.

Are there other ways to accomplish this?

**Update:** I've worded my question wrong. I also want to have a timeout on read operations as well as the connection itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specify connection timeout in java.nio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563934/specify-connection-timeout-in-java-nio)

Comment: No, that's for non blocking mode nio. I'm talking about blocking mode.

Answer (score 2):

`setSoTimeout()` sets a read timeout, not a connect timeout, and for some reason it doesn't work at all on `SocketChannels`, even in blocking mode, and even with wrapped streams.

The method you are looking for is `channel.socket().connect()` with two arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to have a timeout on read operations too. I've updated my question to reflect this too. I asked the question when I was tired last night and forgot to mention it.

Comment: Then I suggest you use `java.net.Socket`, which does have read timeouts.

Comment: The top answer in regard to `setSoTimeout()` not working on `SocketChannel` is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866557/timeout-for-socketchannel-doesnt-work) with a workaround. Tried and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, this is not possible using synchronous operations in `nio`. Socket timeouts set via `Socket.setSoTimeout()` affect reads and writes but not establishing the connection.

Timeout for connecting is different from read/write timeouts even at system library level - see `man 2 connect`, `man 2 setsockopt` and `man 7 socket` for the gory details. So if you want a real, application-controlled timeout when connecting, you need to use the asynchronous connection protocol and the appropriate `Selector`, check `SelectionKey.isConnectable()` and so on. This makes the code quite a bit longer, unfortunately.

I don't have the Java lib sources handy now, but it would be interesting to look into how [`Socket.connect(SocketAddress endpoint,int timeout)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29) is implemented internally - but I believe it's using `select()` inside, too.

Comment: You are mistaken. You can use NIO in blocking mode, and you can obtain both a read timeout and a connect timeout. OP does not have to switch to non-blocking mode. -1

Comment: @EJP I don't quite think so. The code for [SocketChannelImpl.connect()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/nio/ch/SocketChannelImpl.java#498) uses `Net.connect()` which is not passed any timeout value. If you use `SocketChannel.socket()`, you get an instance of `SocketAdaptor` whose [connect() method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/nio/ch/SocketAdaptor.java#SocketAdaptor.connect%28java.net.SocketAddress%2Cint%29) uses async I/O internally. So SO_TIMEOUT seems to not affect SocketChannel.connect().

Comment: Call channel.socket.connect(address, timeout) and you get a connection timeout, like it says on the tin. I didn't say anything about SO_TIMEOUT.

Comment: If you call `SocketChannel.socket().connect(address,timeout)`, you are actually using the plain old `Socket` API - so I wouldn't call this an example of connecting using `nio` which I understand the OP needs.

Comment: What he needs is a way to get a connection timeout starting from the NIO API, and that is the way. He doesn't 'need' any kind of 'NIO API purity', and he doesn't 'need' to implement a timed connect himself with non-blocking mode and a selector when there is already a one-liner that already does exactly that under the hood.